# Best way to speed up a double summation

Tags: python, optimization, sum

My code works, but I need it to run in under 1 second.
How do I do that?

[image: For this summation]

```
import math
import time

t=time.time()
line = input().split(' ')
Alen = int(line[0])
Blen = int(line[1])

A = input().split(' ')
B = input().split(' ')

total=0
for i, Ai in enumerate(A):
    for j, Bj in enumerate(B):
       total+= abs((int(Ai)-int(Bj)))*(int(i)-int(j))

print(total)#, time.time()-t)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `int` on the indices.

Comment: What's the current running time ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It varies, but the output says from 2-5 seconds. But I don't see how that makes sense because it can compute the answer in less time than I can say 'one'.

Comment: Is the time wasted in the loops or in the splits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a bit faster; no way of telling how much without some sample data.

```
import time

def get_ints(s):
    return [int(i) for i in s.split()]

t = time.time()

Alen, Blen = get_ints(input())
A = get_ints(input())
B = get_ints(input())

total = sum(abs(Ai - Bj) * (i - j) for i,Ai in enumerate(A) for j,Bj in enumerate(B))

print(total)#, time.time()-t)
```

Comment: Code won't run since you're not passing anything to `get_ints`

Comment: Could you explain why this is faster?